# MySQL Leaderboard Table

Tags: mysql, subquery, common-table-expression, mysql5

I'm trying to figure out how to Select a specific number of rows from a MySQL table based on WHERE clause. I have a table with 10 dummy users, I want to get 2 previous and 2 next users of specific user with their ranks.

```
user_id  |  points
==================
     10        200
      4        130
      2        540
     13        230
     15        900
     11        300
      3        600
     17        110
     20        140
      1        430
      5        800
```

I achieved adding a column for ranking like:

```
user_id  |  points  |  rank
===========================
     15        900        1
      5        800        2
      3        600        3
      2        540        4
      1        430        5
     11        300        6
     13        230        7
     10        200        8
     20        140        9
      4        130       10
     17        110       11
```

But the problem is that I want only 5 rows. Suppose I'm retrieving data for user with `user_id = 11`. The output should look like this:

```
user_id  |  points  |  rank
===========================
      2        540        4
      1        430        5
     11        300        6
     13        230        7
     10        200        8
```

where `user_id = 11` is in the centre with 2 rows above and 2 below. I have tried nesting UNIONS and SELECT statements but nothing seems to work properly.

Comment: Please don't spam tag RDBMS - tag the single RDBMS you are using and require a solution in.

Comment: What is MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check. And could you post at least 1 of your attempted query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion if you're on MySQL 8+:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT user_id, points,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM mytable)
SELECT cte2.user_id,
       cte2.points,
       cte2.Rnk
FROM cte cte1 
 JOIN cte cte2
 ON cte1.user_id=11
 AND cte2.Rnk >= cte1.Rnk-2
  AND cte2.Rnk <= cte1.Rnk+2
```

Using common table expression (cte) then do a self join with condition of `user_id=11` as base to get the `Rnk` value of `-2` and `+2`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b6e49a692ea2bd7497b9096daf48979)

Since you're on older MySQL version, here's what I can suggest:

```
SET @uid := 11;
SET @Rnk := (SELECT Rnk 
              FROM
                (SELECT user_id, points,
                        @r := @r+1 AS Rnk
                  FROM mytable 
                   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r := 0) r
                   ORDER BY points DESC) v
                  WHERE user_id = @uid);
              
SELECT user_id, points, Rnk
  FROM
(SELECT user_id, points,
        @r := @r+1 AS Rnk
                  FROM mytable 
                   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r := 0) r
                   ORDER BY points DESC) v
 WHERE Rnk >= @Rnk-2
   AND Rnk <= @Rnk+2;
```

If you will only use `user_id` as base, then the only part here you need to change is the `SET @uid`. The remaining queries are just fulfilling your condition of getting two positions above and below the rank retrieved according to the `user_id`. The base query in `SET @Rnk` is the same as the base query for the last one. The idea is to assign `@Rnk` variable with `Rnk` position of `user_id=11` then use it in `WHERE` condition for the last query.

I'm not aware if there's any online fiddle still using MySQL 5.1 but here's probably the closest version to it, [MySQL 5.5 demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=b09be4ec089e35326748ad4804118855).

Comment: No, unfortunately I’m using MySQL 5.1

Comment: So, how did you generate the rank?

Comment: `SELECT user_id, points, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM table, (SELECT @rank := 0) z ORDER BY points DESC`

Comment: I can think of at least a couple of method but I think the one in my updated answer might be easier to understand than the other.